# VC++ UWP app OnNavigatedTo( NavigationEventArgs^ ) won't compile

Tags: visual-c++, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I'm writing a simple UWP app and get errors with a pretty basic (I think so) thing.
I want to pass some data between pages:

```
void BusStat::NewTripPage::CreateTrip_Click( Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e )
{
   this->Frame->Navigate( Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName( TripPage::typeid ), "sometext" );
}
```

Which is okay.
Problems occur on second page:

```
void TripPage::OnNavigatedTo( NavigationEventArgs^ e ) {}
```

That gives compiler error C2509: OnNavigatedTo': member function not declared in 'BusStat::TripPage'.
And when I declare the function:

```
void OnNavigatedTo( NavigationEventArgs^ e );
```

That gives compiler errors C2601 [syntax error] and C2511 ['void BusStat::TripPage::OnNavigatedTo(Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation::NavigationEventArgs ^)': overloaded member function not found in 'BusStat::TripPage']

I must add that an example shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/uwp/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages#3-pass-information-between-pages also won't compile for me because of the same reasons.

Any possible solutions?

Comment: The `override` keyword is optional in C++11 but not in the C++/CX extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the header file, you should declare the method as follows:

```
protected:
virtual void OnNavigatedTo(Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation::NavigationEventArgs^ e) override;
```

You can see this in the UWP Samples repository, for example [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/HomeGroup/cpp/Scenario4_SearchUser.xaml.h).